# I want to make a number of different lists with different names

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create lists called
list1, list2, list3, list4 etc up to listX (where X is just any number given in the function I am trying to make)

I don't know how to do this without manually typing in 
`list1=[]`
`list2=[]`
etc.
Can somebody tell me how to do this in python?

Comment: How about a list of lists?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exec` , but make sure what pass to `exec` is under your control .

```
n = 10
for i in range(n):
    exec('list{0} = []'.format(i))
```

And what i recommend is to use a 2d list (list of lists).

```
a_lists_list = [[] for i in range(n)]
```

you can access any list you want with index.

```
print(a_lists_list[2])
```

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful

Comment: @Biffen Edited , I just give a quick solution and take some typing for recommended solution .